# Android Studio, change JDK JRE path

Tags: android, android-studio, jetbrains-ide, java-home

I have Android studio 3.1 on Ubuntu 18.04 which was working with Oracle Java 10. I have deleted all Java packages and alternatives [according to this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/185250/696880).

Now starting Android Studio I face Fatal error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing

For Eclipse it was easy by changing the path in `.ini` file, but how should I do that for Android Studio or other JetBrains IDEs?

I do not have `JAVA_HOME` in path or `printenv | grep jvm` does not return anything.

Comment: Check https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544879-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under ?

Comment: I dont see <product>.jdk in config folder

Comment: AFAIK it's not there by default as IDE comes with own bundled JDK and you do not need to switch anything. Have you tried installing IDE from scratch? (may also backup config folder and see how it goes).

Comment: Yes, this is what I am doing now :) installing from scratch again